# Azure BOT Framework Unable to deploy at Azure using continuous deployment (Git hub)

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I created one BOT using Azure BOT Framework which is consuming LUIS and QnA maker API. This bot is working fine my DEV but when I am deploying this to Azure using continuous deployment(GitHub), it is returning `502(Bad Gateway)` error. I tried updating **MicrosoftAppId** and **MicrosoftAppPassword** also, but still, I am getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: Are you using c# or node?  What version of the bot.builder package are you using?

Comment: C# and we are using latest version

Comment: This could be related with the issue that we are experiencing of users unable to retrieve or update the password in newly created bots. If that is the case, we are working on a fix. Stay tuned.

Comment: But when we are creating bot using azure bot service and making changes in online editor/VS, and deploying, its perfectly working fine.

Comment: This is not working when i am writing code in my local VS and uploading that to git, and configuring continues deployment at azure end. Where as when i am trying with ngrok to debug my live bot, then also it is working.

Comment: And you're storing the App Id and App Password in the Application Environment Variables, or are they in your Web.Config?  You might try logging them out in the code one to ensure they're actually available at runtime.

Comment: These are part of web.config